# in this python code WHILE loop is not working properly and it is showing this error ""local variable 'Owner_Id' referenced before assignment''''

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I tried everything that I can do :
This code is the portion of MySQL Python connectivity project.
In this I want to get out of while loop by selecting "CHOICE 4"

```
print ("starts")
def parkingdet():
          
           print('=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷==')
           
                     
           print("                                                    ")
           print("<<<<      >>>>")
           print("<<<<       >>>>")
           print("<<<<     >>>>")
           print("<<<<       >>>>")
           
           
           choice1=int(input("Enter Vehicle Type: "))                         
           
           soc7=1
           while soc7 == 1:
               if choice1 == 1:                                                   
                   
                   Owner_Id=input('Enter your Owner ID (stars from 101) : ')            
                   NO1 = int(input("ENTER NO. OF VEHICLES: "))
                   Vehicle="Bike"+"-"+str(NO1)
                   Monthly_Bill = 500*NO1
                   Yearly_Bill = Monthly_Bill*12
                   break
                   
               
               elif choice1 == 2:  
                                               #Entry for Car
                   Owner_Id=input('Enter your Owner ID (stars from 101) : ') 
                   NO = int(input("ENTER NO. OF VEHICLES: "))
                   Vehicle="Car"+"-"+str(NO)
                   Monthly_Bill = 1000*NO
                   Yearly_Bill = Monthly_Bill*12
                   break
                   
                   
               elif choice1 == 3:            
                   Owner_Id=input('Enter your Owner ID (stars from 101) : ')
                   Vehicle="Car,Bike"
                   Monthly_Bill = 1500
                   Yearly_Bill = 1500*12
                   break
                   
                   
                   
               elif choice1 == 4:
                   soc7=0   
                   
               
               else:
                   print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
                   print("<<<<   ❗ >>>>")
                   print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
                   break
               
           
               
           print('=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷==')
           value=(Owner_Id,Vehicle,Monthly_Bill,Yearly_Bill)
           query='insert into parkingdet values(%s,%s,%s,%s)'
            
           cursor.execute(query,value)
           con.commit()
            
           print("-    ",Owner_Id)
           
           print(" <<<<                    >>>>")
           print('=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷=̷==')
           parkingdet() 

       #END OF THIS PORTION
```

The error my console is show is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Owner_Id' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please reformat your code to allow for reproducibility. If this actually is how your script is formatted, to start with you shouldn't call the function you're defining inside the definition of that function

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is helpful to know which line is throwing the error. At first glance, it looks like you only define Owner_Id within the ```if-elif```, but some of  the branches do not have Owner_Id. For instance, if ```choice1 == 4``` do not define Owner_Id.

Comment: You do not define the `Owner_Id` variable if the choice is 4, but you still try to use it after the choices in `value=(Owner_Id...`

Answer (score 0):

you need default values if the user's chois is not in the options or `return None`  instead of break

```
else:
                   print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
                   print("<<<<   ❗ >>>>")
                   print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
                   return None  #not break
```